# function inside window.onload

Tags: javascript, html

I have an external js file that contains `window.onload` at top. I want to call `control.next()` function inside `window.onload` when I click the button that is in a separate HTML file.

```
window.onload = function() {

 control = {

    margin: function(n) {
        sliderContent.style.marginLeft = '-' + n + '00%';
    },

    prev: function() {
        (n === 0) ? n = (slideCount - 1) : n--;
        control.margin(n);
    },

    next: function() {
        alert("next");
        (n < slideCount - 1) ? n++ : n = 0;
        control.margin(n);
    },

    slide: function() {
        move = setInterval(function(){
            (n < slideCount - 1) ? n++ : n = 0;
            control.margin(n);
        }, 4000)
    }
 }

}
```

Button code is:

```
<button class="xy" onclick="">next</button>
```

you can also check fiddle at  http://jsfiddle.net/gLPhr/2/

Comment: In your JSFiddle, it looks like you're trying to use jQuery. Try `$(document).load(function() { // your stuff here });`

Comment: @jrthib the JSFiddle contains valid javascript, there is no need for jQuery

Comment: i want to call next() function when i press button

Comment: @stackErr ah sorry, I saw dollar signs and immediately went to jQuery. Yup looks like its valid javascript after a second pass.

Comment: is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/LPzyb/

Comment: It is basically a slider. what i want is when i click on 'buy now' ,it slide to next page. but ,problem is that i'm not able to call  next() function from the button.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible since the `control`s scope is inside the anonymouys function. I dont see a that you need the `onload` event, remove it and your code should work fine.

Comment: I tried to remove the onload ,but then whole thing stop working.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to expose the control object, yes?

```
var control;

window.onload = function() {

 control = {
...
```

Otherwise, `control` is scoped to `window.onload`, and nothing outside can see it.

Btw, not sure that fiddle is where you want it.

Comment: . i also have one more problem regarding it, if you can help me out..its out of main topic.. ....images i used quite large .i have adjust there widht to 100% and it fit the page. but when i tried to adjust its height to 100% its not working...

Comment: I'd have to see the code in context to know what you're trying to do.  Usually you'd recut the image to the right dimensions.  Is there a div that's trapping the image?  Is this live somewhere?  It looks like it might be a tutorial from the easter egg text.

Comment: yeah its div --> section trapping the image..but is there any way,beside resizing or recutting the image .like i do with width. or just leave it..but thanks again

Comment: It's too hard to tell without more of the site and the css for those elements.  You could have a div of a hard height that doesn't allow the entire image to display, in which case, if you want the whole image to display, you'd have to edit that div's styling.  But, again, probably too hard to tell in the abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the control variable external, and just call the method you need in the onload handler.

> var control = {
>
> ```
> margin: function(n) {
>     sliderContent.style.marginLeft = '-' + n + '00%';
> },
>
> prev: function() {
>     (n === 0) ? n = (slideCount - 1) : n--;
>     control.margin(n);
> },
>
> next: function() {
>     alert("next");
>     (n < slideCount - 1) ? n++ : n = 0;
>     control.margin(n);
> },
>
> slide: function() {
>     move = setInterval(function(){
>         (n < slideCount - 1) ? n++ : n = 0;
>         control.margin(n);
>     }, 4000)
> }
> ```
>
> }
>
> window.onload = control.next